# Hide a function parameter in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I need to backup some data to access it later.

At the interface level, I have two functions:

- `put`: backs up data and returns a `backup_Id`.
- `get`: retrieves data given a `backup_Id`.

My current code requires me to supply these two functions with the backup parameter.

```
import Data.Maybe

data Data = Data String deriving Show

type Backup = [(String,Data)]

put :: Backup -> String -> IO Backup
put boilerPlate a = 
    do let id = "id" ++ show(length (boilerPlate))
       putStrLn $ id ++": " ++ a
       return ((id,(Data a)):boilerPlate)

get :: Backup -> String -> Maybe Data
get boilerPlate id = lookup id (boilerPlate)
```

It works OK.

In the following sample, two values are backed up. The second one is retrieved.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let bp0 = []
    bp1 <- put bp0 "a"
    bp2 <- put bp1 "b"
    let result = get bp2 "id1"
    putStrLn $ "Looking for id1: " ++ show (fromJust(result))
```

But I need to simplify the signatures of `put` and `get` by getting rid of all the backup parameters.

I need something that looks like this:

```
main = do
    put "a"
    put "b"    
    let result = get "id1"
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do it wit an MVar though I cannot in good conscience recommend this. Why not create a backup monad and do your calculations in it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the State monad / StateT monad transformer?

Comment: I am not (yet) familiar with monads, nor the State, nor the Transformer. While looking for a solution to my problem, I've had the impression that it could be the right way to go. I've tried to implement it, but with no success. If someone can "inject a State Monad" in my code, I think that would be the BEST tutorial I could ever find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using `StateT`. Note that the function names are changed because `State` and `StateT` already have `get` and `put` functions.

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad.State

data Data = Data String deriving Show
type Backup = [(String,Data)]

save :: String -> StateT Backup IO ()
save a = do
  backup <- get
  let id = "id" ++ ((show . length) backup)
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ id ++ ": " ++ a
  put ((id, Data a):backup)

retrieve :: String -> StateT Backup IO (Maybe Data)
retrieve id = do
  backup <- get
  return $ lookup id backup

run :: IO (Maybe Data)
run = flip evalStateT [] $ do
  save "a"
  save "b"
  retrieve "id1"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- run
  print result
```

The `State` monad threads a 'mutable' value through a computation. `StateT` combines `State` with other monads; in this case, allowing the use of IO.

As dfeuer mentioned, it is possible to make `save` and `retrieve` a bit more general with these types:

```
save :: (MonadState Backup m, MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
retrieve :: (MonadState Backup m, MonadIO m) => String -> m (Maybe Data)
```

(This also requires `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}`)  The advantage of this approach is that it allows our functions to work with any monad that provides the Backup state and IO. In particular, we can add effects to the monad and the functions will still work.

All this monad / monad transformer stuff can be pretty confusing at first, but it's actually pretty elegant once you get used to it. The advantage is that you can easily see what kind of effects are required in each function. That being said, I don't want you to think that there are things that Haskell can't do, so here's another way to achieve your goal which does away with the state monad in favor of a mutable reference.

```
module Main where
import Data.IORef

data Data = Data String deriving Show
type Backup = [(String,Data)]

mkSave :: IORef Backup -> String -> IO ()
mkSave r a = do
  backup <- readIORef r
  let id = "id" ++ ((show . length) backup)
  putStrLn $ id ++ ": " ++ a
  writeIORef r ((id, Data a):backup)

mkRetrieve :: IORef Backup -> String -> IO (Maybe Data)
mkRetrieve r id = do
  backup <- readIORef r
  return $ lookup id backup

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ref <- newIORef []
  let save = mkSave ref
      retrieve = mkRetrieve ref
  save "a"
  save "b"
  result <- retrieve "id0"
  print result
```

Just be warned that this isn't usually the recommended approach.

Comment: This answers perfectly my question.  Now, is there a way to adapt it to use `save` and `retrieve` directly at the ghci level with something like 
*Main> save "a"  
*Main> id0: a  
*Main> save "b"  
*Main> id1: b  
*Main> let result = retrieve "id1"

Comment: You could write your own Monad instance, but you'll still need some kind of `runState`-like function to supply the initial state. I think what you're suggesting would require a top-level mutable reference, which is not idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: You might consider using `MonadState s m` and `MonadIO m` contexts rather than directly using `StateT s IO`.

Comment: Thank you so much @user2297560 ! I've decided to study the monads for good now. Your two exemples and your explanations will help me a lot to finally master this concept.